# footnote referencing of line number

Tags: footnotes, linenumber

I started working with `XeLaTeX` yesterday and almost have footnotes displaying correctly. My problem is that the references to `line number` with `\linelabel` and `\lineref` doesn't work correctly such that each `footnote` would automatically reference the line number of a word in-text. I have `lne:label1` and `lne:label2` to collect either line number, but I would rather not make a new `label3,4`,etc. for each line.

Is it possible to fix this with a `\counter` or `\variable` function? Please help any suggestions will be most appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[modulo, pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

textline1\linelabel{lne:label1}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{lne:label1}} textline1} text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text textline6\linelabel{lne:label2}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{lne:label2}} textline6} text \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe, you should look on reledmac package.

Answer (score 0):

sort of fixed with...

```
\refstepcounter{counterB}\linelabel{\thecounterB}\blfootnote{\textbf{\lineref{\thecounterB}} textline1}
```

?? shows up instead of line number for some footnotes...? and it's not working for footnotes on the same line :(